# Complex json ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to ng-repeat on this object, I tried several times but still stuck. If anyone have an idea, and if it's possible to share tips for this kind of situation.

```
[
{
    "Abonnement": {
        "id": "1",
        "nom": "BAS PRIX",
        "tarif": "2.49",
        "communication": "2h de communication",
        "vers": "vers fixes et mobiles",
        "zone": "zone nationale"
    }
},
{
    "Abonnement": {
        "id": "2",
        "nom": "NATIONAL",
        "tarif": "9.99",
        "communication": "t\u00e9l\u00e9phonie et SMS illimit\u00e9s",
        "vers": "vers fixes et mobiles",
        "zone": "zone nationale"
    }
},
{
    "Abonnement": {
        "id": "3",
        "nom": "EURO",
        "tarif": "19.99",
        "communication": "t\u00e9l\u00e9phonie et SMS illimit\u00e9s",
        "vers": "vers fixes et mobiles",
        "zone": "zone EURO"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Please show us your `ng-repeat` code and describe the specific problem you're having.

Comment: ng-repeat="abonnement in abonnements" (i assume your var holding the collection is named abonnements) with abonnement.Abonnement.id  /  abonnement.Abonnement.nom to get the values. Did you try this ?

Comment: Thanks Okazari ! It was an orthographic error in my scope...

Answer (score 2):

If the array is stored in the scope under `$scope.abonnements`, this is how you would use `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in abonnements">{{ item.Abonnement.nom }}</li>
</ul>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/89b98cpd/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have name your object something like Abonnements

```
  $scope.Abonnement = [..your example json]
```

Then you'd just use the ng-repeat like

```
  <div ng-repeat="Abonnement in Abonnements">
      id: {{Abonnement.Abonnement.id}}
  </div>
```

And access the information with `Abonnement.Abonnement.id` for example. So if you wanted the vers, it would be `Abonnement.Abonnement.vers` .